# Error: 'value': keys_to_typing(value)} while sending keys selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login into website using selenium but i am getting errors while sending username and password to the website:

code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path='../chromedriver')

driver.get('https://secure.imdb.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fap-signin-handler&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=imdb_pro_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&siteState=eyJvcGVuaWQuYXNzb2NfaGFuZGxlIjoiaW1kYl9wcm9fdXMiLCJyZWRpcmVjdFRvIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcm8uaW1kYi5jb20vdjIvbmFtZS9ubTM0NzUyMDk_cmY9Y29uc19ubV9tZXRlciZyZWZfPW5tX3B1Yl91cHNsYl9sb2dpbiJ9&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&imdbPageAction=login')
driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password").send_keys("pass")
driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit").click()
```

it is giving error:

> driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email").send_keys("username")
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
>       'value': keys_to_typing(value)})

chrome version:

> chrome=70.0.3538.77

chrome driver version:

> chromedriver=2.43.600229

how to resolve this ?

Comment: Please add the **full** error traceback as code-formatted text to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you cannot handle authentication form without clicking `"Log in with IMDb"` link. Try to click it before sending keys:

```
# driver.find_element_by_id('login_with_imdb_expender').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log in with IMDb').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password").send_keys("pass")
```

Comment: thanks great answer :). i tried so many things but this didn't strike my mind because before clicking on that also i was able to find the element(i printed it on the console) but some how it didnot work that time

Answer (score 1):

As per the [IMDb](https://secure.imdb.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fap-signin-handler&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=imdb_pro_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&siteState=eyJvcGVuaWQuYXNzb2NfaGFuZGxlIjoiaW1kYl9wcm9fdXMiLCJyZWRpcmVjdFRvIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcm8uaW1kYi5jb20vdjIvbmFtZS9ubTM0NzUyMDk_cmY9Y29uc19ubV9tZXRlciZyZWZfPW5tX3B1Yl91cHNsYl9sb2dpbiJ9&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&imdbPageAction=login) website before sending the *character strings* to **Email** and **Custom password** field you have to click on the *link* with text as **Log in with IMDb** inducing *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://secure.imdb.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Fap-signin-handler&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=imdb_pro_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&siteState=eyJvcGVuaWQuYXNzb2NfaGFuZGxlIjoiaW1kYl9wcm9fdXMiLCJyZWRpcmVjdFRvIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcm8uaW1kYi5jb20vdjIvbmFtZS9ubTM0NzUyMDk_cmY9Y29uc19ubV9tZXRlciZyZWZfPW5tX3B1Yl91cHNsYl9sb2dpbiJ9&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&imdbPageAction=login')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-expander-prompt']/span[@id='login_with_imdb_expender']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='a-input-text a-span12 auth-autofocus auth-required-field' and @id='ap_email']"))).send_keys("aravind_reddy")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='a-input-text a-span12 auth-required-field' and @id='ap_password']").send_keys("aravind_reddy")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='a-button-input' and @id='signInSubmit']").click()
```

Comment: Can you share some clarifications about WHY OP need to use WebDriverWait in this case and WHY overcomplicated locators should be used instead of simple locators as I see no benefits from your answer in comparison to my answer?